# ¿Cómo revierto los valores de una cadena de caracteres en c#?

Tags: c#, string

Quiero invertir los caracteres de mi cadena de texto en *C#*.

Es decir, que si recibo una cadena, por ejemplo `ABDCF`, devuelva `FCDBA`.

Comment: Que tipo de dato es `dato[5]`, no quisiera _explayarme_ pero algo me dice que quieres hacer, por ejemplo, algo como `20171231` de tu objeto `31/12/2017`; donde `dato[5]` podría ser un `DateTime`. :)

Comment: @Davlio si, estas en lo correcto

Comment: tienes un formato en particular de las fechas?

Comment: @David [puedes revisar los formatos que se puede dar a una fecha](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Comment: brother, eres un usuario con más de 600 puntos, no crees que cuando hay preguntas en cascada se deba crear nuevas preguntas en vez de actualizar N veces la misma?

Comment: @fredyfx buen punto, creo que lo tomare en cuenta, saludos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Título de la pregunta:

> ¿Cómo revierto los valores de una cadena de carácteres en
>   c#?

Dentro de la descripción

> que si obtengo una cadena "ABDCF", quiero hacer que los valores sean
>   "FCDBA"

Detalles de revisión: https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/55905/2

Para hacer funcionar lo que necesitas, utiliza el siguiente método:

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```